# Can level 1 characters survive a fall of several miles?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, encounter-design, falling, session

I'm going to start a new campaign soon, and I thought it would be fun to scare my players in the first session by having them start the game falling from the sky.

The thing is, I don't wanna kill them in the very first session, but the only ways I can think of for a level 1 character to not take damage from a fall that high up is feather fall (no spellcasters), or that feature monks get until 4th level.

Should I just scrap that idea entirely?

I feel like there has to be a way of dropping them from that high up without killing them, but I also don't want to just have them conveniently fall on hay or something like that. I want them to be the ones to figure out how not to die, but I can't even figure it out myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can 16th-level characters mitigate damage from a lethal (long) fall?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160176/how-can-16th-level-characters-mitigate-damage-from-a-lethal-long-fall)  It's about higher level characters, but the highest rated answers should apply to level 1 characters as well.

Comment: If you cannot figure out the way by research and forethought, do you think players will come up with a solution in the spur of the moment? Unfortunately,  it sounds like you're fishing for ideas as opposed to looking for a single correct answer.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Most of my answer will rely on introducing IRL reasoning into the equation.

Falling in general has a speed limitation, named Terminal Velocity, a speed at which the air drag doesn't allow the falling body to have any more acceleration. In DnD 5e, this speed is indicated by 20d6 max damage, which is, admittedly, more than a 1st level character can survive.

In real life, there were cases of people falling from planes and surviving, which ultimately comes down to a set of fortunate circumstances related to nailing the landing one way, or another.

First of all, the stuff you're landing on is important. From the best to the worst:

1. Swamp
2. Snow
3. Grass

These will cushion the fall, I'd say you can deduct a few hit dices if the players land into this.

Additionally, falling through stuff like tree branches or glass panes can also slow down the fall and, while not painless, also increases surviveability (I'd say, deal some damage on impact, subtract 1-3 dices of damage from the fall per each).

Meanwhile bodies of water are basically a trap card in this scenario - just like meeting their surface with a high horizontal speed, falling into them at a terminal velocity would be the same as falling on rocks.

As such, my suggested course of action is this:

- Give them the means to steer themselves during their fall. Could be anything from a Mage Hand to a fantasy equivalent of a jumpsuit. IRL, humans can pretty much do it even without that, but depending on your players, it could introduce a bad precedent
- Give them a choice of where to land. If you don't want to give them a chance to fail, don't introduce a body of water as a choice.
- Introduce something to slow down their fall somewhat. A bunch of trees, some glass panes, or a bunch of somewhat easily tearable cloths. Maybe even a bunch of explosives at the landing site - if one of the adventurers has a fire spell, you could allow them to time out igniting it so that the updraft can cushion/stop their fall.

In the end, remember that even with all of these in mind - they won't be dusting themselves off and walking away after a fall like this. Best case scenario, they'll have just a few HP left (and, realistically speaking, a lot of fractures and bruises all over their bodies). More realistically speaking, after surviving this they'll require complete bed rest, and help from a cleric strong enough to mend bones